# Firestore how to handle more than 10 IN equalities

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use the "IN" operator to query documents related to a user's friends. However, as per Firestore documentation:

> Cloud Firestore provides limited support for logical OR queries. The in, and array-contains-any operators support a logical OR of **up to 10 equality** (==) or array-contains conditions on a single field. For other cases, create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app.

Say if I have a "friends" array containing 100 objects, then calling `db.collection("chats").whereField("creator", in: friends)` would give some errors, I assume.

If the limit is 10, then how would I "create a separate query for each OR condition and merge the query results in your app"?

I intend to apply snapshot listeners and a pagination capability to the query as well, what would be the most performant and recommended way of approaching this?

Answer (score 3):

> Say if I have a "friends" array containing 100 objects, then calling db.collection("chats").whereField("creator", in: friends) would give some errors, I assume.

Yes, that is correct. You get an error message that sounds like this:

> Invalid Query. 'in' filters support a maximum of 10 elements in the value array.]

One way to work around this limitation is to retrieve the documents in batches, and then process the results from each query on the client.

Another way for solving this problem would be to model your data in a way that doesn't require the above operation. It's hard for me to provide a structure for that, but in most cases, it involves duplicating the data so impossible queries become possible. You can also try to model the data into a single aggregated document, as long as you stay under the [maximum 1 Mib limitation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

Comment: Is there any plan that this limit will be extended to some bigger number ... for example 100, 1000, ... etc? ;)

The problem with batches are, that some friends can have newer items and we should show them, but with batches we will show for each friend eqaul number of items, even if those are not so important ...

Comment: @PeterZagoranski I don't know if they will actually change those limitations.

Comment: 10 limit is laughable, I wish I've never started the project in firebase. It seems like every minute I save from using it costs me an hour to deal with their limitations, crappy documentation, not being able to implement trivial stuff etc.